# Using ProcessModuleCollection to look for all DLLs loaded by an .exe does not detect all of them?

Tags: c#, windows, dll, process

I have a requirement to check whether a custom .dll has been loaded by an .exe using a c# app running under windows.
The solution I've tried for this locates the .exe fine, and detects *most* of the .dlls used by the .exe, but not all, and it's the one it's failing to find that is the one I'm looking for.
I have used the Process Explorer utility from SysInternals as a cross-check, and this does find the .dll I'm looking for associated with the .exe, indicating that what I'm trying to do is possible.
The c# code fragment, picks up 106 DLLs for my .exe whereas the "Process Explorer" utility picks up 110 :

```
                Process[] myProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyExe");
                foreach (var dllProc in myProc)
                {
                    ProcessModuleCollection PMC = dllProc.Modules;
                    for (int i = 0; i < PMC.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var myPMC = PMC[i];
                        if (myPMC.ModuleName.StartsWith("MyDLL"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Found the DLL : " + myPMC.ModuleName);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Does anyone know why this approach wouldn't pick up every .DLL ?
I'm new to how windows manages .exes and .dlls etc..., but the only difference I can think of is that maybe ProcessModuleCollection is constructed when the .exe is first loaded up, and any .dlls loaded after the initial start-up are then missed.
Is there an alternative method using c# to get this information ? Any help is welcome !

Comment: If you fear that Modules is a presummably wrong cached value you might try calling dllProc.Refresh() before.

Comment: Is that 64 bit exe ? ProcessModuleCollection won't show the 32 bit dll's in the list of a 64 bit process.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The .dll it can't find is definitely 64-bit (built using x64 option). The common theme between the ones it can't find and the ones it can seems to be when it's loaded. Just wish I knew how the Process Explorer was doing it...